# How to assign or reset the address[] payable variable in solidity 0.5.2 or above?

Tags: javascript, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, remix

The version I'm using is **0.5.2**

I'm executing the below code in **Remix IDE**

```
pragma solidity  ^0.5.2;

contract Lottery {
    address public manager;
    address payable[] public players;

    constructor () public {
        manager = msg.sender;
    }

    function enter() public payable {
        require(msg.value > 0.01 ether);
        players.push(msg.sender);
    }

    // function getPlayers() public view returns(address[] memory) {
    //     return players;
    // }

    function random() public view returns(uint) {
        return uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.difficulty, now, players)));
    }

    function pickWinner() public {
        uint index = random() % players.length;
        players[index].transfer(address(this).balance);
        players = new address[](0); // This line of code giving an error
    }
}
```

**The error I'm getting is:**

```
Type address[] memory is not implicitly convertible to expected type address payable[] storage ref.
```

in the function pickWinner():

```
function pickWinner() public {
    uint index = random() % players.length;
    players[index].transfer(address(this).balance);
    players = new address[](0); // This line of code giving an error
}
```

I'm trying to reset my players' array all to 0 so as to reset my Lottery contract

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the best/easiest thing to do is `players.length = 0`.

Note that this will use gas proportional to the number of elements in the array (because it deletes all of them). If this is a problem, you might want to consider using a mapping instead with a separately stored length. E.g.

```
mapping(uint256 => address payable) players;
uint256 playersLength;
```

Then just do `playersLength = 0` to "reset."

**EDIT**

Per the comments, it sounds like you're not seeing the gas usage based on the size of the array. Here's a simple way to test in Remix:

```
pragma solidity 0.5.2;

contract Test {
    uint256[] foo;
    uint256[] bar;

    constructor() public {
       for (uint256 i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
           foo.push(i);
       }
       for (uint256 i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
           bar.push(i);
       }
    }

    function deleteFoo() external {
        foo.length =  0;
    }

    function deleteBar() external {
        bar.length = 0;
    }
}
```

In my testing, using the JavaScript VM, `deleteFoo` consumes 26,070 gas, and `deleteBar` consumes 266,267 gas.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @smarx. I will use your suggestion in my trial code. I am still doubtful about the gas consumption for deleting the elements and as i.m trying it in test network(ie, Javascript VM environment in Remix Ide) I didn't notice any consumption of gas.

Comment: See my edit for a way to test the gas consumption of deleting arrays.

Answer (score 1):

```
function pickWinner() public {
    uint index = random() % players.length;
    players[index].transfer(address(this).balance);
    players = new address payable [](0); //add payable to this line
}
```

Comment: The answer would be more useful if you can add some explanation along with the code.